# Trouble with Youtube iframe API

Tags: api, audio, iframe, youtube

I currently have a blog that plays background music when you load the page using a youtube iframe:

```
<iframe id="background-music" width="0" height="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VOR8reYWvx8?rel=1&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1" xframeborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have imported the youtube iframe api manually as well:

```
<script src="http://url_to_script/iframe_api.js"></script>
```

I have other songs on my blog and I want to pause the background song whenever I play one of the other songs on there. I have the following code, per the instructions on https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples, but it doesn't work at all.

```
$(".tumblr_audio_player").contents().find('.play_button').click(function() 
                console.debug(YT);

                player = new YT.player("background-music", {
                    events: {
                      'onReady': function() { console.log("player is ready") },
                      'onStateChange': function() { console.log("player has changed state"); }
                    }
                });
                player.stopVideo();
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I don't know if onReady and onStateChange are required (I don't need them), but it doesn't work without the second object parameter so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: I've never seen `xframeborder="0"` before, usually it's `frameborder="0"`, note: that isn't a fix, merely an observation. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: well, I found one mistake: it should read "new YT.Player(...)" instead of "new YT.player(...)". Now it's saying that player.stopVideo() (or pauseVideo) aren't functions.....

Comment: I have no idea what this is: `$(".tumblr_audio_player").contents().find('.play_button').click(function() 
                console.debug(YT);
` without a [mcve] I have no way of testing a fix, hence whatever I do to help is guessing. Good luck.

Comment: I was creating a jsFiddle to show you, zer00ne. https://jsfiddle.net/w01yyesk/ I want the music that autoplays to stop when you click on the video that's not playing. This is just an example however, and as you noted, my blog uses the tumblr audio player in the iframe for the other songs that are not the autoplaying song. That part of the code so far is working and isnt the problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out what was going on. The code is mostly correct, however, initializing the YT.Player object takes time which is exactly what the onReady callback is for.

It makes sure that the YT object is initialized before you do anything. If you put the pauseVideo in the onReady callback, it will work properly. So to answer my original question, onReady is absolutely necessary:

```
player = new YT.Player("background-music", 
{   events: {
        onReady: function() {
            player.stopVideo();
        }
    }
});
```